# vba excel how to check if cell not empty and color the entire row?

Tags: excel, if-statement, is-empty, vba

i have VBA code that compare dates of the user input with the current dates and fill the background by the appropriate color. all it works fine.

now i need to make the system to check if the  cell in column **F**  of the selected row **is not empty** i need to colored the column **D,E,F** in  gray color.

## code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = xlNone

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

i will appreciate any help

Comment: use conditional formatting

Comment: @Rosetta no i need to add it in my code

Comment: `if cells(i,6) <> "" then cells(i,3).entirerow.interior.color = vbRed`... does this solve your problem?

Comment: @Dany7elo see my answer and code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check also if `Trim(Range("F" & i).Value) <> ""` in the relevant criterias.

I've also modifed the logic of your current code to be shorter and faster to run through (switched to `Select Case`, etc.)

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim NumofDays As Long

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'
    Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = xlNone ' set as inital color, only change if all criterias are met

    NumofDays = CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - Date

    Select Case NumofDays
        Case Is < 0
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        Case 0
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

        Case 1 To 4
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

        Case 5 To 10
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

    End Select

    ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "F" is not empty
    If Trim(Range("F" & i).Value) <> "" Then Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.Color = ... ' selectyourcolor 
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: i do not want to make the entire row colored Green or red ...if i want to just fill the column **D,E,F**  with a gray color  and the rest of the column stay as it is in my code ... i will edit my question

Comment: @Dany7elo see edited code, replace the part i wrote `... ' selectyourcolor` with the color you want to put there

Comment: your code is working but still have one problem that is even if the cell(i,3) is empty the cell will be colored Green.... WHAT I WANT IS if the (i,3) is empty must not be colored

Comment: for this reason i thing the IF statement will be better right ?

Comment: yes  i told you it work perfectly but still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting is easiest, just [a few clicks](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/29/excel-change-row-background-color/#change-row-color).

> 1. Start with selecting the cells the background color of which you want to change.
> 2. Create a new formatting rule by clicking Conditional Formatting > New Rule... on the Home tab.
> 3. On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting > New Rule... In the "New Formatting Rule" dialog window that opens, choose the option "Use
>      a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter the following
>      formula in the "Format values where this formula is true" field:
>      =$C2>4
> 4. Open the 'New Formatting Rule' dialog and enter the needed formula. Instead of C2, you enter a cell that contains the value you want to
>      check in your table and put the number you need instead of 4. And
>      naturally, you can use the less (<) or equality (=) sign so that your
>      formulas will read =$C2<4 and =$C2=4, respectively.
> 5. Also, pay attention to the dollar sign $ before the cell's address, you need to use it to keep the column letter the same when the formula
>      gets copied across the row. Actually, it is what makes the trick and
>      applies formatting to the whole row based on a value in a given cell.
> 6. Click the "Format..." button and switch to Fill tab to choose the background color. If the default colors do not suffice, click the
>      "More Colors..." button to pick the one to your liking, and then click
>      OK twice.

Comment: I think the question was to do the conditional formatting programmatically.