# Excel, different row highlight color when cell value change

Tags: excel, colors, highlighting

I have a big excel file and how improve readability, I'd like to have some sort of visual marker (color, border etc.). What would work great is a different highlight color (for the row) when the cell value of the first column change. Can that be done automatically or is there a excel feature that can improve readability.

What I have in mind is something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `when the cell value of the first column change`?  Change from what to what?   What if the value is changed a second time, or changed back to the original -- should it still be highlighted? Can you give some more detailed before & after examples?

Answer (score 0):

With **Conditional Formatting** you can change the color of a row based on the value of a cell.  See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808494/8112776

If you're not looking for a specific value but rather "any change", then more information is needed: Define `when the cell value of the first column change`?  Change from what to what?   What if the value is changed a second time, or changed back to the original -- should it still be highlighted, or is this a permanent change?  Can you give some more detailed before & after examples?